# No sound in .mp4 file converted with x264

Tags: sound, video

Hello i am trying to convert some avi files to mp4 files to be able to use it with my chromecast via castplayer in Chronium. I tried with x264 converter, the conversion works but i have no sound in the .mp4 video. Here is the command i use:

x264 file.avi -o file.mp4

Thank you.

Comment: `x264` is a *video* encoder. It cannot encode or multiplex *audio* data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert avi (xvid) to mkv or mp4 (h264)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370786/how-to-convert-avi-xvid-to-mkv-or-mp4-h264)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html), (a ffmpeg gui) it is the ideal tool for this.

[image]