# MP4 video converter splitter joiner

Tags: mp4

Converting splitting and joining mp4 files in Windows is as simple as eating drinking and sleeping but here in Ubuntu it is giving me all kind of headaches to find a simple software to perform the tasks. Can someone suggest a software that can convert split and join mp4 files without writing endless commands that hardly works?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059506)?

Comment: You could also just concatenate the contents into a new file.

Comment: Again that's a string of commands that look like an essay. I am looking for a software like we have  ultra video converter splitter and joiner in Windows. I wonder why Ubuntu is fascinated about complicating things

Comment: Give Openshot or Avidemux a try, works very well on my Ubuntu 14.04 and Arch.

Comment: Because people who use Ubuntu are sick and tired of Windows's way of making things that should be simple very complicated, even if they make complicated things simple.

Answer (score 1):

I use handbrake for all my video conversion.

It is very simple to use, and easy to figure out.

never tried it for merging or splitting video files, so cannot comment on how it handles it.

but looking at this post [No sound in .mp4 file converted with x264](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684777/no-sound-in-mp4-file-converted-with-x264)

dmMediaConverter looks like it will do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html). It does that just fine. First use **split** them **merge the same**. These operations are quick, no reencoding involved.
[image]